# Tumblr API: requesting read-only access

Tags: oauth, omniauth, tumblr, oauth-ruby

I'm hooking up my application to the Tumblr API, and when I try and authorize I get the message "Grant this application read and write access to your Tumblr account?". I only want read access to users' accounts.

The [Tumblr API docs](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/applications) say you can have read-only or read and write access.

> Permission will either be for read and write or read access. Read and write access permits the application or web site to create and edit your posts.

How do I tell oAuth to only request read access from the Tumblr API?

With the Twitter API, apparently you can change the access level of your apps: http://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1274. I don't see anything like that in the Tumblr oauth admin settings: http://tumblr.com/oauth/apps

Here's a relevant thread in the Tumblr API discussion group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tumblr-api/HuDoDBvTIMI

Comment: The only reference to it that I could find, was in the Tumblr Developer Group on Google Groups and no one seems to know how to get read-only to work, not even the Group Moderators who work for Tumblr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly I think this [link](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/applications) needs updating as the only mention of **read only** is in the old API (v1): http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v1

The new API (v2) has no mention of **read only** and requires OAuth, no matter the mode: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no read only access in tumbler.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/tumblr-api/HuDoDBvTIMI/_MpTulouo-0J